# execute script tags when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, mailchimp

I currently have two script tags that run when the page loads. These are the last thing in the BODY.

I now want them to run when i click a button. How is this possible to do?

HTML COde

```
<div class="col-md-12 signup-wrap">
            <a class="signup blue-grdt" href="#">Newsletter Signup</a>
        </div>
```

Script

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us12.list-manage.com","uuid":"xx","lid":"xx"}) })</script>
```

Comment: You can add them to the dom/page when you click a button

Comment: You would require the embed.js file using [Jquery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) and execute the code on the second script tag inside the success callback. Other option would be inject the tags on the DOM by trigger a function when the user clicks the button, but be careful, that would open a security issue.  [This answer](https://community.optimizely.com/t5/Using-Optimizely/Insert-JS-Code-from-MailChimp-with-Optimizely/m-p/17073/highlight/true#M6375) may give you more ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would try something like this:

```js
function getScript() {
  let script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = "//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js";
  script.setAttribute("data-dojo-config", "usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false")
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  setTimeout(function() {
    require(
      ["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {
        L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us12.list-manage.com","uuid":"xx","lid":"xx"})
      }
    )  
  }, 2000);
  console.log('getScript executed');
}

let button = document.getElementById('newsletter-signup');
button.addEventListener('click', getScript);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 signup-wrap">
  <a id="newsletter-signup" class="signup blue-grdt" href="#">Newsletter Signup</a>
</div>
```

However I don't recommend to inject scripts this way because it would expose your code to security issues.

UPDATE: I updated this to be an snippet, everything running.

UPDATE#2: Based on your comment I changed the way to add the event to the button, this time I added directly to the element by getting it whit it's id and using addEventListener to attach the action.

Comment: Hi @codeNinja I updated the solution to be an snippet, it is working fine, however could you please double check the function is defined in a javascript file correctly called in your html code, or try to put it in an <script> tag in the html body, that may would help.

Comment: I have placed <script> tags right under the html code but i still get the "getScript() not found". Only note is that the code is being added to my header file which is then added to all pages. The Header is part of the BODY

Comment: Hi @codeNinja I added an update where now we are attaching the event to the button by getting it with JS directly, as you can see in the updated snippet. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i no longer get the error but nothing happens. I dont see the `console.log` statements print anything in the devconsole

Comment: Did you add the `id="newsletter-signup"`  to the anchor tag?, for some reason it is running in the snippet but not on your code.